# Python: MyVariable = MyVariable + 1 not stacking?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a rock paper scissors program, it has a random choice maker and repeats itself. I am trying to implement a Game counter and Win Counter. But every time it resets itself back to zero. I have tried many things and have tried to search but haven't figured out how to solve this.

```
def everthing():

    import time
    from random import randint

    original = input("Enter 'Rock', 'Paper' or 'Scisors: ")

    word = original.lower()
    Player_win_count = 0
    PC_win_count = 0
    Game_count = 0

    if word == "rock":
        no = randint(1,3)
        if no == 1:
            print ("The Computer chose Rock. It's a tie\n")
            Game_count += 1
            print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))
        if no == 2:
            print ("The Computer chose Paper. You Lose!\n")
            Game_count += 1
            PC_win_count += 1
            print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))
        if no == 3:
            print ("The Computer chose Scisors. You win!\n")
            Game_count += 1
            Player_win_count = 1
            print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))

    if word == "paper":
        no = randint(1,3)
        if no == 1:
            print ("The Computer chose Rock. You Win\n")
            Player_win_count += 1
            Game_count += 1
            print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))
        if no == 2:
            print ("The Computer chose Paper. It's a tie!\n")
            Game_count += 1
            print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))
        if no == 3:
             print ("The Computer chose Scisors. You lose!\n")
             PC_win_count += 1
             Game_count += 1
             print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))

    if word == "scisors":
        no = randint(1,3)
        if no == 1:
            print ("\nThe Computer chose Rock. You Lose!\n")
            PC_win_count += 1
            Game_count += 1
            print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))
        if no == 2:
            print ("\nThe Computer chose Paper. You Win!\n")
            PC_win_count += 1
            Game_count += 1
            print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))
        if no == 3:
            print ("\nThe Computer chose Scisors. It's a tie!\n")
            Game_count += 1
            print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))

        everything()


    else:
        print ("That is not a valid entry. Please try again")
        everything()

    everything()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thom is correct that your problem can be solved with global variables, but there is a greater underlying problem: making a function loop by calling itself over and over, will eventually cause a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error after the user plays 999 rounds. If you want the function to loop, just use a `for` or `while` loop. This will incidentally solve your value resetting problems. Additionally, you should probably be using `elif` instead of `else` if you want your "that is not a valid entry" message to appear at the right time.

```
import time
from random import randint

Player_win_count = 0
PC_win_count = 0
Game_count = 0

while True:
    original = input("Enter 'Rock', 'Paper' or 'Scisors: ")
    word = original.lower()
    no = randint(1,3)

    if word == "rock":
        if no == 1:
            print ("The Computer chose Rock. It's a tie\n")
            Game_count += 1
        if no == 2:
            print ("The Computer chose Paper. You Lose!\n")
            Game_count += 1
            PC_win_count += 1
        if no == 3:
            print ("The Computer chose Scisors. You win!\n")
            Game_count += 1
            Player_win_count += 1
        print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))

    elif word == "paper":
        if no == 1:
            print ("The Computer chose Rock. You Win\n")
            Player_win_count += 1
            Game_count += 1
        if no == 2:
            print ("The Computer chose Paper. It's a tie!\n")
            Game_count += 1
        if no == 3:
            print ("The Computer chose Scisors. You lose!\n")
            PC_win_count += 1
            Game_count += 1
        print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))

    elif word == "scisors":
        if no == 1:
            print ("\nThe Computer chose Rock. You Lose!\n")
            PC_win_count += 1
            Game_count += 1
        if no == 2:
            print ("\nThe Computer chose Paper. You Win!\n")
            PC_win_count += 1
            Game_count += 1
        if no == 3:
            print ("\nThe Computer chose Scisors. It's a tie!\n")
            Game_count += 1
        print ("The games played are: " + str(Game_count) + "\n      The scores are:\n                 You: " + str(Player_win_count) + "\n            Computer: " + str(PC_win_count))


    else:
        print ("That is not a valid entry. Please try again")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variables are in the scope of the function `everything()`. That means they get initialised every time you call the function again. You should define them **outside** of the function, that way they only get initialised when your program is first loaded.

(You should also move your imports to the top of the file, otherwise every `everything()` call will import them again)

Example:

```
def a():
    myvar_a = 10
    myvar_a += 1
    print(myvar_a)  # will print 11, every time

myvar_b = 10
def b():
    global myvar_b  # otherwise we can only read myvar_b and
                    # ... not reassign it to myvar_b = myvar_b + 1
    myvar_b += 1
    print(myvar_b)  # will print 11, 12, 13....
```

By the way, there's also one line where you do `Player_win_count = 1` instead of `+= 1`.

Comment: When I run `b()` in your sample, I get `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: Right, to reassign primitives you need to use `global`

Comment: When possible, I'd recommend simply having the function return the new values instead of relying on `global`.

Comment: Agreed, but there are several style problems with this program. Unnecessary recursion, var names, repeated code (`no = randint()`)....

Comment: when I put them outside the `everthing():` i get UnboundLocalError. I see you said to use global.... I am still new to coding and don't know what this is.

Comment: if you assign a variable in an inner scope, such as inside a function, python assumes you want to create a new variable. The `global` keyword signals "No, I want you to use the global scope version".

Comment: could you give me an example of how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're defining those counters within the function. Once the function exits, all of those values are thrown away. To solve this, have that function return the updated values, then save them whenever you call it.

```
def everything():
    ...
    return player, pc, games

player_wins, pc_wins, games = everything()
```

Also, imports should go in the global scope (at the top of the program), not within functions.